# All Longest Strings.

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, methods

I'm new to coding. I want to return all longest strings of equal length. When I run it I get:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
at arrayOfStrings:8:10
```

I know that it is looping and hitting the call limit. Is this salvageable or is there a better way? Thanks for your help!

```
function arrayOfStrings(allLLongestStrings) {

allLLongestStrings => {
let maxLng = Math.max(...arrayOfStrings.map( elem => elem.length))
return arrayOfStrings.filter(elem => elem.length === maxLng)
}
return arrayOfStrings();
}

arrayOfStrings(
[
'otorhinolaryngological', 
'Otorhinolaryngological', 
'Psychophysicotherapeutics', 
'Thyroparathyroidectomized', 
'Pneumoencephalographically', 
'Radioimmunoelectrophoresis', 
'Psychoneuroendocrinological', 
'Hepaticocholangiogastrostomy', 
'Spectrophotofluorometrically', 
'Antidisestablishmentarianism'
]
);
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Is `arrayOfStrings` a function or an array, so that you do `filter` on it? Why is there an arrow function within a function? Please, fix your naming, remove naming conflicts and fix your syntax.

Comment: you have a mixup of array names and function names.

Comment: `return arrayOfStrings();`

You have a recursive call that takes zero parameters and no base case to break out of your recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a different approach by reducing the array and checking if the actual string is longer than the last stored one, then take a new array with this string, otherwise check the length and if it has the same take the string for the temporary result set.

```js
function getLongestStrings(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, s, i) => {
        if (!i || r[0].length < s.length) { // first or longer string
            return [s];
        }
        if (r[0].length === s.length) {     // same length
            r.push(s);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

console.log(getLongestStrings(['otorhinolaryngological', 'Otorhinolaryngological', 'Psychophysicotherapeutics', 'Thyroparathyroidectomized', 'Pneumoencephalographically', 'Radioimmunoelectrophoresis', 'Psychoneuroendocrinological', 'Hepaticocholangiogastrostomy', 'Spectrophotofluorometrically', 'Antidisestablishmentarianism']));
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the array by length and then picking out the first element of the array.

```
function arrayOfStrings(arr) {

return arr.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0]

}
```

I'm sorry if you intended something else, but I couldn't understand your code so I figured
you wanted the string with the maximum length in the array.

Comment: Before posting a ambigous answer, please consider to comment and find out what the question exactly is about.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an approach I would take to get the longest strings from the array. The code comments explain the logic:

```js
function getLongest(a) {
  //Find the length of the longest word in the array
  var maxLength = Math.max(...a.map(s => s.length));
  //Return array after filtering words with length less than maxLength.
  return a.filter(s => s.length === maxLength);
}

console.log(getLongest([
  'otorhinolaryngological',
  'Otorhinolaryngological',
  'Psychophysicotherapeutics',
  'Thyroparathyroidectomized',
  'Pneumoencephalographically',
  'Radioimmunoelectrophoresis',
  'Psychoneuroendocrinological',
  'Hepaticocholangiogastrostomy',
  'Spectrophotofluorometrically',
  'Antidisestablishmentarianism'
]));
```

This code will only work in an ES6 environment as it takes advantage of [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

```
function allLongestStrings(inputArray) {
    const s = inputArray
    const m = inputArray.map((e) => {
        return e.length
    }).sort((a, b) => b - a)[0]
    
    return s.filter((b) => {
        if ( b.length === m ) return b
    })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please extend your answer with further information and explanations, so it is not just an unexplained block of code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
function longest(array) {
  let longitud = array.length;
  const arreglo = [];
  maximaLongitud = array.sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)[0].length
  console.log(maximaLongitud)
  for (let i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
    if (array[i].length === maximaLongitud) {
      arreglo.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return arreglo;
}
```